# What are the views of Islam towards cultural diversity such as polytheistic or Idolatre festivals?

Tags: anger, social-media

Adaab.

I often listen that Islam has an intensely  negative perception towards cultural diversity especially towards those religions don't have a particular book, or have a polytheistic culture, or practices idolatry festivals. But is this true? or it tells about peace and tolerance? Which one is true?

Personally I have seen in social media that many many Muslims harshly criticise the 'other' cultures, and especially when Muslim people/ people with Arabic names actively engage in peace and communal harmony like attending or helping in the festivals of 'the other culture', some other Muslims start to aggressively hold them back or putting bad comments.

My question is, does such intolerance or aggression supported by Islam?

Edit: I totally acknowledge *islamophobia* or aggression towards Muslim ethnicity is another burning problem. This question is not for generalising any religion (islam or christian or any others) is more tolerant or less tolerant. My question is whether certain rude or aggressive act of a population of  specific individuals are permissible/promoted by islam or not. The question is less about Islam itself but *more about the individual engaging in vandalism or aggression over the 'other' cultures.*  This include rude comments in social media or vandalizing sculptures etc. or any kind of aggression given that the 'other' culture did not incited any violence or aggression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "harshly" is a loaded word. You must separate two things, the religion of Islam itself (theology) and culture.

### Islamic View

In Islam, Shirk (associating partners of any sort with Allah) is absolutely haram and is considered the biggest sin in Islam. Participating in any religious festival that is not in Islam is haram as that would be celebrating untruths. Though respecting those who practice those festivals, having good relations, and engaging in friendly and civic dialogue with them is encouraged.

[Quran 13:16](https://quran.com/13?startingVerse=16)

> Ask ˹them, O  Prophet˺, “Who is the Lord of the heavens and the earth?” Say, “Allah!” Ask ˹them˺, “Why ˹then˺ have you taken besides Him lords who cannot even benefit or protect themselves?” Say, “Can the blind and the sighted be equal? Or can darkness and light be equal?” Or have they associated with Allah partners who ˹supposedly˺ produced a creation like His, leaving them confused between the two creations? Say, “Allah is the Creator of all things, and He is the One, the Supreme.”

[Quran 4:116](https://quran.com/4?startingVerse=116)

> Surely Allah does not forgive associating ˹others˺ with Him ˹in worship˺, but forgives anything else of whoever He wills. Indeed, whoever associates ˹others˺ with Allah has clearly gone far astray.

You can read more about it in-depth here: [Why Is Shirk the Greatest Sin of All?](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/read/paper/why-is-shirk-the-greatest-sin-of-all)

###### Dealing Justly and fairly with others

So Islam has a complete rejection of polytheism of any sort but this doesn't forbid Muslims in acting kindly, fairly, and befriending those that are non-Muslim.

[Quran 60:8](https://quran.com/60?startingVerse=8)

> Allah does not forbid you from dealing kindly and fairly with those who have neither fought nor driven you out of your homes. Surely Allah loves those who are fair.

[Quran 60:9](https://quran.com/60?startingVerse=9)

> Allah only forbids you from befriending those who have fought you for ˹your˺ faith, driven you out of your homes, or supported ˹others˺ in doing so. And whoever takes them as friends, then it is they who are the ˹true˺ wrongdoers.

### Cultural Aspect

People will have varying levels of likeliness of another religion, ethnicity, race, etc based on numerous factors such as politics, nationality, their own culture, and more.

One must evaluate their own perception. Maybe a comment or post you see as aggressive or intolerant could actually not be aggressive/intolerant and just a condemnation of what these people (Muslims participating in non-Islamic activities) are doing in order to help guide them according to their faith.

Also, there's a lot of hate on the internet by non-muslims against Muslims, Islamophobia is a very rampant problem across the world unfortunately, so if there are Muslims that'll hold negative perceptions of other groups, it wouldn't be surprising and could be reactionary.

- [Islamophobia and the Law: Unpacking Structural Islamophobia](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/read/paper/islamophobia-and-the-law-unpacking-structural-islamophobia)
- [Islamophobia in American Society, Culture, & Politics](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/read/paper/islamophobia-in-american-society-culture-politics)
- [From India, Islamophobia Goes Global](https://foreignpolicy.com/2020/07/01/india-islamophobia-global-bjp-hindu-nationalism-canada/)

What we can all do is do our best to be kind to others, respect each other's beliefs, and debate through peaceful means if desired.

### Conclusion

A practicing Muslim will avoid haram and dislike it so if they see a Muslim promoting haram, they'll have a distaste for what that Muslim is doing since the activity they're doing goes against Islam and often times will encourage other Muslims to fall into sin (by doing that activity).

Though a Muslim should always try their best to be professional/diplomatic in their speech and to be kind to others whether they are Muslim or non-Muslim as long as they don't have a justifiable reason to be aggressive against them.

Comment: I have replaced the word 'harshly' by 'intensely' and added a clarification at the end of the question.

Comment: I recommend learning all about the formatting tools [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/editing-help) you can learn *how to format links* and more.

Comment: Will do, thanks